# Giant parsnip from Korean shop

Tags: vegetables, food-identification, korean-cuisine

I bought a vegetable from a Korean food store which all I can describe as is a parsnip with the same dimensions but about two feet long.
Is there a name for this?

Comment: Do you have it still? Can you include an image?

Comment: @Catija not with me, but I will tomorrow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like [Daikon Radish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daikon) to me. It is commonly found in Korean supermarkets and looks slightly like parsnip. Some can grow longer than 2 feet.

[image]

Another possibility is [Parsley Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsley#Root_parsley). These look very similar to Parsnips but are generally not as bulbous near the top, longer and more slender.

[image]

Comment: That's my guess, too...

Comment: I was thinking immediately of daikon as well :) The parsley roots I've seen are smaller than parsnips.

Comment: What is the flavor of parsley root like? It certainly LOOKS like a parsnip!

Comment: @Erica, unsurprisingly parsley root taste a lot like parsley leaves. It is a clean, "fresh" flavor very unlike parsnips which has a slightly pungent but nutty sweet flavor.